# CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider (Android) - how to logout and remove cached credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using the developer-authenticated technique for implementing this class, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#using-developer-authenticated-identities).  So far, I've been able to implement this class and build a framework in which I check CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId() to see if a user has logged in (and therefore doesn't need to re-authenticate by entering an email and password). To do this, I'm using a series of static methods in a class called Util, since these only need to be instantiated once. This is what it looks like:

```
package com.pranskee.boxesapp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.*;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

public class Util {
    private final static String TAG = "Util";

    private static final String AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = {acct id};
    private static final String COGNITO_POOL_ID = {pool id};
    private static final String COGNITO_ROLE_AUTH = {auth arn};
    private static final String COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH = {unauth arn}

    private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sCredProvider;
    private static UserIdentityProvider sIdProvider;
    private static CognitoSyncManager sSyncManager;

    private Util() {
    }

    public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(
            Context context) {
        if (sCredProvider == null) {
            if (sIdProvider == null) {
                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider tmpProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                        context.getApplicationContext(), AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
                        COGNITO_POOL_ID, COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH,
                        COGNITO_ROLE_AUTH, Regions.US_EAST_1);
                if (tmpProvider.getCachedIdentityId() != null) {
                    sCredProvider = tmpProvider;
                } else {
                    sCredProvider = null;
                }
            } else {
                sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                        context.getApplicationContext(), sIdProvider,
                        COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH, COGNITO_ROLE_AUTH);
            }
        }
        return sCredProvider;
    }

    public static UserIdentityProvider getIdentityProvider(Context context,
            String email, String pwd) {
        if (sIdProvider == null) {
            sIdProvider = new UserIdentityProvider(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
                    COGNITO_POOL_ID, context.getApplicationContext(), email,
                    pwd);
            Map logins = new HashMap();
            logins.put({Developer Provider Name}, sIdProvider.getToken());
            sIdProvider.setLogins(logins);
        }
        return sIdProvider;
    }

    public static boolean isLoggedIn(Context context) {
        if (getCredProvider(context) == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static CognitoSyncManager getSyncManager(Context context) {
        if (sSyncManager == null) {
            sSyncManager = new CognitoSyncManager(
                    context.getApplicationContext(), Regions.US_EAST_1,
                    sCredProvider);
        }
        return sSyncManager;
    }

    protected static class UserIdentityProvider extends
            AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider {

        private Context context;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public UserIdentityProvider(String accountId, String identityPoolId,
                Context c, String em, String pwd) {
            super(accountId, identityPoolId);
            context = c;
            email = em;
            password = pwd;
        }

        @Override
        public String refresh() {
            try {
                ServerCommunicator server = new ServerCommunicator(context);
                //this is a server call, which makes the call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest after I authenticate the user and send AWS my user's token
                String response = server.initUserLoginAsyncTask()
                        .execute(email, password).get();
                JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
                String identityId = responseJSON.getString("id");
                String token = responseJSON.getString("token");
                this.setToken(token);
                this.setIdentityId(identityId);
                update(identityId, token);
                return token;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getProviderName() {
            return {Developer Provider Name};
        }

    }

}
```

Now, I want to also implement a Logout.  I think what I'd need to do is remove the cached Identity Id somehow, but I'm not sure what the best method would be to do that. Or, maybe it's not that at all, and I need to do something differently entirely.  Either way, I just want to implement the intended behavior of allowing a user to select to "Log Out" of my app, which causes Cognito to forget that that ID was logged into the Identity Pool and invalidates any attempt to establish an Identity ID again without going through my authentication process again.

Answer (score 2):

Logout would be a two steps process, first you need to logout from the Identity Provider that authenticated your user (Amazon, Google, Facebook or your own)  Instructions on how to do this are specific to your provider.

From the CognitoIdentity side, you need to tell the CredentialsProvider to clear all state and cache associated with your identity.  Using Android SDK, you can call clear() on the CredentialsProvider (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCredentialsProvider.html)

Comment: OK, the second part makes sense.  But, I'm not sure how to execute the first part. I'd need to invalidate the developer identity token I created initially to log the user in.  Any idea how to do that? My server-side is using the PHP SDK

Comment: It depends on the provider you are using to authenticate your user ?  Are you using Login With Amazon ?  Google ?  Facebook ?  Your own provider ? If you are using Login With Amazon, the doc is here http://login.amazon.com/android and you need to call mAuthManager.clearAuthorizationState()

Comment: My own provider. I see a method called unlinkDeveloperIdentity, but I don't think that's what I want.

Comment: Sorry - second reading of your comment - I understand you are using your own provider (Developer Provided Identity) - You logout from your own backend system.  How you do that depends on your backend system.  Their no server side backend call to make a logout

Comment: OK, I'm confused. For my auth, I send a token from my backend to Cognito, which tells it which IdentityId and OpenId token to provide my user with. Wouldn't I need to invalidate that OpenId token in order to properly invalidate her credentials?

Comment: There is no invalidate token API on the server side.  The token you receive is valid only for a short period of time (15 min by default, up to 60 min) and automatically expire after that period (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html)

Comment: hmmm, interesting... i wonder what the logic is behind that? it seems to me like there should be a way to force invalidation of the token.  i guess removing the credentials from the device is enough... thanks for your help

Comment: @ethan123 OpenId Connect id tokens (which Cognito uses) have no method for invalidation of the token, this is a limitation of the specification. You can make your tokens shorter lived if you are worried about reuse or simply make sure to delete the token after use.